# How to drop variables from a model created from the mlr package in R?

Tags: r, mlr

This is somewhat similar to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845108/how-to-remove-a-variable-from-a-model-using-iml-package-in-r). However, that question as zero answers and I think this question might be more fruitful in getting a response.

What I am trying to do is remove some features from an `mlr` created model, without having to fit the model again. For example, if we take the `Boston` data from the `MASS` library and create an `mlr` model, like so:

```
library(mlr)
library(MASS)

# Using the mlr package to train the data:
bTask  <- makeRegrTask(data = Boston, target = "medv")
bLearn <- makeLearner("regr.randomForest")
bMod <- train(bLearn, bTask)
```

And then I use the `task` and trained `model` in some function, for example:

```
someFunc <- function(task, model){
  pred <- predict(model, task)
  pred <- pred$data$response
  head(pred,10)
}
someFunc(bTask,bMod)
```

Everything works fine. But Im wondering if it's possible to remove some variables from `bMod`, without having to fit the `mlr` trained model again?

I know it's possible to drop features from the `task` using `dropFeatures()`, for example:

```
bTask1 <- dropFeatures(bTask, c("zn", "chas", "rad"))
```

But if I try to mix `bTask1` and `bMod` like so:

```
pred1 <- predict(bMod, btask1)
```

I get the sensible error:

> Error in predict.randomForest(.model$learner.model, newdata =
>   .newdata,  :    variables in the training data missing in newdata

Is there a way of dropping some features from the `mlr` created model (i.e, `bMod`) without fitting it again?

Comment: No. This is not a limitation of mlr, but of statistical machine learning in general.

Comment: I was fearing something like this... so inevitably, I would have to do the `makeLearner` and `train` processes again... there's no way around it